# XCode - Function in library not linked

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have added a library to my cocoa application and used some of the classes and functions in them.
When i build my project a get a error which states

> "Function_Name", referenced from:
>         -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I had initially used only one class which ran without error, for addition of a new feature i needed to use another function which wasn't present in the same class, which produced this error.
This function has been used many times in previous projects but all of them have been command lines applications whereas this one is a cocoa application (Will this cause any difference?)
In order to check if the function has been properly included i click the function name and use the "Jump to Definition" feature, it correctly shows me where the function is.
I would like to know why does this error occur and also the means to work around it